# getting wifi status in iphone

Tags: iphone

please suggest me how to get the wifi status in iphone/itouch. the reachability code given by apple doesnt work consistently. Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211GetInfoCopy ?